# MVC Save multiple keywords from Texbox into database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Texbox where I get multiple `keywords` with an autocomplete jQuery script from database. How do I send data to the controller when my `Textbox` is like this: `@Html.TextBox("search")` and I also have multiple values, all with different IDs.

And how do I store multiple values ? I can have a `list` or an `array`? Or I modify the posts table and I add the tags there? Or I make a third model to store the posts with tags?

I am so confused right now, how do I extract the values from `Textbox` and send them to the controller and then store them in db.

Give me some suggestions how you have solved this issue before please.

**EDIT:**

My relationship between Job and in Tags is like this:

*Job Model:*

```
[ForeignKey("Tags")]
public int TagId { get; set; }

public virtual Tags Tags { get; set; }
```

*Tag Model:*

```
[ForeignKey("Jobs")]
public int JobID { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
```

The `script` I think is useless to posts since its working fine and I just need to take values from it and save them in `JobTable` along with `TagID`, but I am confused how to store multiple values of the same `TagID` with just one `JobID`. I am pretty sure I am *overthinking* this. For now I am trying to do this `string[] keywords = Request.Form["search"].Split(',');` as suggested below.

This is how I create a Job:

```
       var jobs = new Job
       {
            //Non-Visible for users
            ID = job.ID,
            DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
            DateExp = expireDate,

            //UI Submit Data
            DescJob = job.DescJob,
            Name = job.Name,

            //Relational Tables 
            XP = xp.Exp.ToString(),
            UserID = LoggedUserId,     

            //Here the magic
            //Just an example how I think
            TagID = // Here values from my @Html.TextBox("search")
        // If there are 2 3 4 values in textbox its very logical to do it with a foreach 
        // and get every ID and then store them. I still don't understand how my database 
        // will look like

        };
```

For now I am trying @Yanga Answer. Seems very close to what I want to do.

Comment: Your property needs to be `int[] search` (or `string[] search` depending of what type of data your returning)

Comment: ya, i think you can store your multiple values in one textbox with delimiter (comma (,) for instance) -> pass it to controller.
in controller it is better to create new Custom ModelBinding and bind with the model. The ModelBinding itself is just to split the values and return as List<your model>.
something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input "search" have a delimiter for exemple coma ",".
You can extract the keywords in your controller
with the split function :

```
string[] keywords = Request.Form["search"].Split(',');
```

or with your model:

```
string[] keywords = model.search.Split(',');
```

---

To save each keywords in your database:

```
        foreach (var keyword in keywords)
        {

            var KeywordsDBQuery = db.YourKeywordsTable.Where(k => k.Keyword == keyword).FirstOrDefault();
            if (KeywordsDBQuery == null)
            {
                KeywordsDBQuery.DomainName = keyword;
                db.YourKeywordsTable.Add(KeywordsDBQuery);
            }

        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I am trying right now your answer. And yes I use a comma in Textbox. I edited my Question for more details. Thank you.

Comment: Well I used only `Request.Form["search"]` and saved like this: `TagNames = keywords`. I was over thinking this. Now when I show them and want to display their description with a hover I just have to make a search where the UI string match the databases string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a [select2](https://select2.github.io/options.html) plugin not the autocomplete, it will give you the option to select more than one value in a nice way, it renders a `select` element with `multiple=true`, so what will be submitted is an array of values.

You can have your action with one parameter of type `string[]` or `List<string>`

so, your view should look like:

```
@Html.DropDown("search")
@section scripts
{
//Include select2 scripts here
 <Script>
   $("#search").select2({...}) //configure it here with the URL for the autocomplete values
 </script>
}
```

and in your action:

```
public ActionResult Search(List<string> search)
{
}
```